# SQL Server data inserted but response not received by client

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I have a Java jdbc client inserting data to a table in SQL server. At some point SQL server is stopped gracefully. My client receives this exception

```
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:2392)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:2376)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.read(IOBuffer.java:1900)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.readPacket(IOBuffer.java:6674)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.startResponse(IOBuffer.java:7989)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.doExecuteStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:901)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement$StmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerStatement.java:796)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7535)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2438)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:208)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:183)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeUpdate(SQLServerStatement.java:721)
```

However, when the SQL server is started, I can see that this data is actually inserted in my table.

I would like to know

1. Stop behavior of SQL server. Whether the server can insert data and stop without replying back to the client
2. Any issue with JDBC driver or client that is not able to correctly handle SQL server stopping.
3. Is something like roll forward happening after the SQL server is started.

Any help or pointers on how to analyze this scenario would be very much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Changes are made durable once committed on the server side. The change is durable even if acknowledgement can't be delivered to the client.

Comment: Thank you Dan. Does SQL service stop not ensure to send a response back for committed changes before actually shutting down ?

Comment: A graceful shutdown will wait for running queries to finish but it does not guarantee a response is returned to the client. So if your command is a single autocommit insert statement that completed, it will be committed but the response may or may not be returned depending on the timing.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Dan.